# Error of neural networks does not converge

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, julia

I'm using julia to create a neural network with TensorFlow.

My networks runs but the error does not converge, here is the TensorBoard result:

[image]

To check my error function, I used the tutorial of [Malmaud](https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl/blob/master/examples/mnist_full.jl) and I replaced "accuracy" by my function.

It works:

[image]

Following that, I think my network has a problem.

Can you help me ?

Here is my code:

```
ENV["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0" # It is to use the gpu
using TensorFlow
using Distributions

sess = Session(Graph())

batch_size = 30  
num_pixels = 64

###########

# Data base: 1000 arrays, the first array is fill with 1, the second with 2 etc...

arrays_data = zeros(Float32,1000,num_pixels,num_pixels)

arrays_labels = zeros(Float32,1000)

for k in 1:num_pixels, j in 1:num_pixels, i in 1:1000
        arrays_data[i,j,k] = i
end

for i in 1:1000
    arrays_labels[i] = i
end

###########

# inputs

x = placeholder(Float32, shape= [batch_size, 1, 1, 1])

y = placeholder(Float32)

###########

 # Function to create a batch

function create_batch(batch_size)
    x = zeros(Float32, batch_size,num_pixels, num_pixels)
    y = zeros(Float32, batch_size)

index = shuffle(1:1000) # To choose a random batch

    for i in 1:batch_size
        x[i, : ,:] = arrays_data[index[i],:,:]

        y[i] = arrays_labels[index[i]]
    end
    y, x
end


###########


# Summary to use TensorBoard

 summary = TensorFlow.summary

# Create the different layers ; poids = weight

variable_scope("mymodel" * randstring(), initializer=Normal(0, .001)) do
    global poids_1 = get_variable("p1", [2,2,2,1], Float32)
    global poids_2 = get_variable("p2",[4,4,3,2],Float32)
    global poids_3 = get_variable("p3",[2,2,4,3],Float32)
    global poids_4 = get_variable("p4",[1,4,4,4],Float32)
    global poids_5 = get_variable("p5",[1,4,4,4],Float32)
    global poids_6 = get_variable("p6",[1,4,4,4],Float32)
    global biases_1 = get_variable("b1",[2],Float32)
    global biases_2 = get_variable("b2",[3],Float32)
    global biases_3 = get_variable("b3",[4],Float32)
    global biases_4 = get_variable("b4",[4],Float32)
    global biases_5 = get_variable("b5",[4],Float32)
    global biases_6 = get_variable("b6",[4],Float32)
end

logits_1 = nn.relu(nn.conv2d_transpose(x, poids_1, [batch_size,2,2,2], [1,2,2,1],padding = "SAME") + biases_1)

logits_2 = nn.relu(nn.conv2d_transpose(logits_1,poids_2, [batch_size,4,4,3], [1,2,2,1],padding = "SAME") + biases_2)

logits_3 = nn.relu(nn.conv2d_transpose(logits_2,poids_3, [batch_size,8,8,4], [1,2,2,1],padding = "SAME") + biases_3)

logits_4 = nn.relu(nn.conv2d_transpose(logits_3,poids_4, [batch_size,16,16,4], [1,2,2,1],padding = "SAME") + biases_4)

logits_5 = nn.relu(nn.conv2d_transpose(logits_4,poids_5, [batch_size,32,32,4], [1,2,2,1],padding = "SAME") + biases_5)

 logits_6 = nn.relu(nn.conv2d_transpose(logits_5,poids_6, [batch_size,64,64,4], [1,2,2,1],padding = "SAME") + biases_6)

logits_6 = reduce_sum(logits_6, axis=[4])



logits = reshape(logits_6, [batch_size,num_pixels*num_pixels])  # Output of network




smax = nn.softmax(logits)



cross_entropy = reduce_mean(-reduce_sum(y.*log(smax))) # loss function

optimizer = train.AdamOptimizer(0.0001)

train_op = train.minimize(optimizer,cross_entropy)

error = (1/(num_pixels*num_pixels*batch_size)).*sqrt(sum((smax - y)^2))

 summary.histogram("Error",error)

 merged = summary.merge_all()

run(sess, global_variables_initializer())

# summary_writer = summary.FileWriter("Folder Path") # If you want use TensorBoard

# Train loop

for i in 1:500

batch = create_batch(batch_size)


x_ = run(sess, train_op, Dict(x => reshape(batch[1], (batch_size,1,1,1)), y => reshape(batch[2], (batch_size,64*64))))


  if i%100 == 1

    err = run(sess, error, Dict(x => reshape(batch[1], (batch_size,1,1,1)), y => reshape(batch[2], (batch_size,64*64))))
       info("train $i , error = $err")
       end

# If you use TensorBoard, please use the following commands

      # new = run(sess,merged, Dict(x => reshape(batch[1], (batch_size,1,1,1)), y => reshape(batch[2], (batch_size,64*64))))

      # write(summary_writer, new, i)

end

close(sess)
```

**EDIT**

The following code is working:

```
using TensorFlow
using Distributions

sess = Session(Graph())

batch_size = 30
num_pixels = 256

###########

# Data base: 10000 arrays, the first array is fill with 1, the second with 2 etc...

arrays_data = zeros(Float32,10000,num_pixels,num_pixels)

arrays_labels = zeros(Float32,10000)

for k in 1:num_pixels, j in 1:num_pixels, i in 1:10000
            arrays_data[i,j,k] = i
end


for i in 1:10000
    arrays_labels[i] = i
end

###########

# inputs

x = placeholder(Float32, shape= [batch_size, 1, 1, 1])

y = placeholder(Float32)

###########

 # Function to create a batch

function create_batch(batch_size)
    x = zeros(Float32, batch_size,num_pixels, num_pixels)
    y = zeros(Float32, batch_size)

index = shuffle(1:10000) # To choose a random batch

    for i in 1:batch_size
        x[i, : ,:] = arrays_data[index[i],:,:]

        y[i] = arrays_labels[index[i]]
    end
    y, x
end


###########


# Summary to use TensorBoard

 summary = TensorFlow.summary

# Create the different layers ; poids = weight

variable_scope("mymodel" * randstring(), initializer=Normal(0, .001)) do
    global poids_1 = get_variable("p1", [3,3,2,1], Float32)
    global poids_2 = get_variable("p2",[3,3,3,2],Float32)
    global poids_3 = get_variable("p3",[3,3,4,3],Float32)
    global poids_4 = get_variable("p4",[3,3,4,4],Float32)
    global poids_5 = get_variable("p5",[3,3,4,4],Float32)
    global poids_6 = get_variable("p6",[3,3,4,4],Float32)
    global poids_7 = get_variable("p7",[3,3,8,4],Float32)
    global poids_8 = get_variable("p8",[3,3,8,8],Float32)
    global biases_1 = get_variable("b1",[2],Float32)
    global biases_2 = get_variable("b2",[3],Float32)
    global biases_3 = get_variable("b3",[4],Float32)
    global biases_4 = get_variable("b4",[4],Float32)
    global biases_5 = get_variable("b5",[4],Float32)
    global biases_6 = get_variable("b6",[4],Float32)
    global biases_7 = get_variable("b7",[8],Float32)
    global biases_8 = get_variable("b8",[8],Float32)
end

logits_1 = nn.relu(nn.conv2d_transpose(x, poids_1, [batch_size,2,2,2], [1,2,2,1],padding = "SAME") + biases_1)

logits_2 = nn.relu(nn.conv2d_transpose(logits_1,poids_2, [batch_size,4,4,3], [1,2,2,1],padding = "SAME") + biases_2)

logits_3 = nn.relu(nn.conv2d_transpose(logits_2,poids_3, [batch_size,8,8,4], [1,2,2,1],padding = "SAME") + biases_3)

logits_4 = nn.relu(nn.conv2d_transpose(logits_3,poids_4, [batch_size,16,16,4], [1,2,2,1],padding = "SAME") + biases_4)

logits_5 = nn.relu(nn.conv2d_transpose(logits_4,poids_5, [batch_size,32,32,4], [1,2,2,1],padding = "SAME") + biases_5)

 logits_6 = nn.relu(nn.conv2d_transpose(logits_5,poids_6, [batch_size,64,64,4], [1,2,2,1],padding = "SAME") + biases_6)

logits_7 = nn.relu(nn.conv2d_transpose(logits_6,poids_7, [batch_size,128,128,8], [1,2,2,1],padding = "SAME") + biases_7)

logits_8 = nn.relu(nn.conv2d_transpose(logits_7,poids_8, [batch_size,256,256,8], [1,2,2,1],padding = "SAME") + biases_8)

logits_8 = reduce_sum(logits_8, axis=[4])


logits = reshape(logits_8, [batch_size,num_pixels*num_pixels])  # Output of network


# Don't use a softmax here...


least_square = reduce_mean(sqrt(sum((y - logits).^2))) # Loss function

optimizer = train.AdamOptimizer(0.0001)

train_op = train.minimize(optimizer,least_square)


error = sqrt(sum((y - logits).^2)./(num_pixels.*num_pixels.*batch_size))

 summary.histogram("Error",error)

 merged = summary.merge_all()

run(sess, global_variables_initializer())

# summary_writer = summary.FileWriter("Folder Path") # If you want use TensorBoard

# Train loop

for i in 1:1500

batch = create_batch(batch_size)


x_ = run(sess, train_op, Dict(x => reshape(batch[1], (batch_size,1,1,1)), y => reshape(batch[2], (batch_size,num_pixels*num_pixels))))


  if i%100 == 1

    err = run(sess, error, Dict(x => reshape(batch[1], (batch_size,1,1,1)), y => reshape(batch[2], (batch_size,num_pixels*num_pixels))))
       info("train $i , error = $err")
       end

# If you use TensorBoard, please use the following commands

       # newer = run(sess,merged, Dict(x => reshape(batch[1], (batch_size,1,1,1)), y => reshape(batch[2], (batch_size,num_pixels*num_pixels))))

       # write(summary_writer, newer, i)

end

close(sess)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this problem.

Three main points:

- The tutorial of Malmaud applies a softmax to the output of the network because there are different possible results and the best one (with the higher probability) must be chosen. In this case, the output is a picture and we don't have to apply a softmax ; just compare the output with the input.
- For the loss function, a cross entropy is not needed, a least square method  is chosen.
- There is not enough data with only 64 pixels, so a database with 256 pixels is better.

I added my new code to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Does `error` need to be defined as a function?

Something like:

`error(smax, y) = (1/(num_pixels*num_pixels*batch_size)).*sqrt(sum((smax - y)^2))`

Comment: Thank you for your proposition but it is not resolving the problem. There is exactly the same error.

Comment: If it trains well with the built in error function, and this is the only addition, then I would start there. What are the variables y and smax? I am accustomed to having a y_pred from the network and a y_true to compare to.

Comment: In your case, y is y_true and smax is y_pred  (It is smax because it is the output of a softmax function...)

Comment: Maybe change your script to be identical to Malmauds (Its a bit different - no @tf begin / end for instance, etc) and then adjust it one step at a time until you get the issue you see.

Comment: What is the "@tf begin / end"  ?  I tried with just one layer and it did not work...

Comment: The Malmaud script you link to.

Comment: Ok. I used @tf begin / end ; I declared the weights and biases with the Malmaud method (function weight_variable and bias_variable). But the error still not converge. I don't see another big differences with the Malmaud tutorial...

Comment: I noticed the code that does work uses .^ in the error function, whereas the code that does not uses ^
(smax - y)^2 vs. (y - logits).^2